How to send data in background React Native IOS?
I have an app that records audio during the night. To not send the whole audio file at the end, I managed to write native modules to split the recording into 15-minute chunks to send them while the recording is still going.
I found a way how to send these chunks using react-native-background-fetch. Below is the code:
useEffect(() => {
    if (isRecordingStart && id) {
      const uploadExistingChunk = async () => {
        if (id && isRecordingStart) {
          const chunkPosition = chunkLength.current
          const fileName = `sound-${dayjs(recordingStartDate.current).format(
            RECORDING_NAME_DATE,
          )}_${chunkPosition}`
          const outputFileName = `${PATH_RECORDS_FOLDER}/${fileName}.${FILE_MIME_TYPE}`

          const isExist = await isFileExist(outputFileName)

          if (!isExist) return

          await dispatch(
            sendRecordingChunk({
              id,
              recordingPath: outputFileName,
              position: chunkPosition,
              onSuccess: () => {
                chunkLength.current = chunkPosition + 1
              },
            }),
          )
        }
      }

      BackgroundFetch.configure(
        {
          minimumFetchInterval: 16,
          stopOnTerminate: false,
          startOnBoot: true,
          enableHeadless: true,
          requiredNetworkType: BackgroundFetch.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY,
        },
        async (taskId) => {
          console.log('[BackgroundFetch] taskId: ', taskId)
          await uploadExistingChunk()
          BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('[BackgroundFetch] configure error:', error)
        },
      )

      BackgroundFetch.status((status) => {
        switch (status) {
          case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_RESTRICTED:
            console.log('BackgroundFetch restricted')
            break

          case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_DENIED:
            console.log('BackgroundFetch denied')
            break

          case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_AVAILABLE:
            console.log('BackgroundFetch is enabled')
            break
        }
      })

      return () => {
        BackgroundFetch.stop()
      }
    }
  }, [isRecordingStart, id, dispatch])

This approach works perfectly fine for Android, but I have issues with IOS. Chunks are not sent in the background, they all are sent only when I stop the recording.
Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue?
